# How do I create new transformation categories in SAS DI Studio?

Tags: sas, sas-dis

In SAS DI Studio I create custom transformations from time to time. This is useful, but all custom transformations appear under the "Ungrouped" tab category within the transformation tree.

This is unwieldy and it would be helpful if I could create new categories to group these custom transformations into.

Is that possible to do, and if so, how?